# How to give space between images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am building my own website with Dreamweaver. I have an portfolio page with an gallery which I used from this tutorial: http://www.webdesigntunes.com/coding/jquery-filterable-portfolio/#comment-16950

The images from the tutorial are smaller but I want them bigger like: 324 by 322 px.
Also they make a columm of 4 images next to each other and I want to have 3 to each other.
But when I try that, my images don't go perfectly next to each other.

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="portfolio">

    <article class="entry video">
        <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="#">
        <img class="top" src="images/knop-1.jpg" alt="">
        <span class="magnifier"></span>
        </a>
    </article>
```

(this article div repeats for every new image)

Some of the CSS:

```
.portfolio { 

width: 960px;
height:auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
margin:15px; 

}

.magnifier {



background:url(images/knop-hover1.jpg) no-repeat center;
    width:324px;
    height:322px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
}

img.top {

position:absolute;
left:0;
right:5px;

}
```

I hope you guys can help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You want 3 images in a row. One image has `324px width` so it makes 324*3 = `972px`. But portfolio has `960px width`. First thing you need to do is fix that considering the gap you want between images too.

Comment: `img.top { width: ; height: ;}`

Comment: Agree to @BatuZet, you have 960px fixed with so u need to have your image size less than 320px. Or approx around 260px or something.

Comment: looking at your supplied html and css, I would expect all your images to stack on top of each other at the top right of your portfolio div

Comment: If youre trying to set gaps between images with those `left` and `right` values, what you need are `margin-left` and `margin-right`

Comment: Of course! But now when I did that it makes no difference.
This is a screenshot how it looks like right now: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img841/8726/34gb.png

this is the code from the demo of the filter gallery btw: http://jsfiddle.net/fuCjY/

Comment: @user3564651 What else are you wanting? If you're just wanting that centered, look at my answer.If you're wanting space between them, look at my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the JQuery from the tutorial. You'll need to add that before it all works like the demo. I notice you're missing a closing `/div` tag and your img tag should close itself at the end like this: `/>` instead of just `>`.

If you want three images instead of four you can make them auto center by applying a width to a surrounding div that encompasses the individual images. Then that surrounding `div` needs to be inside a larger content `div` or main `div`. The main `div` will have a set width, `float`ed left. Then you can set `margin:0 auto;` for the surrounding `div` and it will center everything. You can add some `margin` to the single image `div`s to give them some breathing room, too. I made a code snippet so you can see visually what I mean.

```css
.main {
  width: 700px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background: pink;
}

.surrounding {
  width: 510px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.single {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.single img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="surrounding">
    <div class="single">
      <img class="top" src="http://www.wallpaperfunda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="single">
      <img class="top" src="http://www.wallpaperfunda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="single">
      <img class="top" src="http://www.wallpaperfunda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="surrounding">
    <div class="single">
      <img class="top" src="http://www.wallpaperfunda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="single">
      <img class="top" src="http://www.wallpaperfunda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="single">
      <img class="top" src="http://www.wallpaperfunda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

An observation, though. 3 images at 324px width are going to be at least 976px when side by side. That is larger than the width you've set for your page. Maybe you're referring to their sized once clicked?

Comment: Thanks for the comment I am really glad you made it in JSFiddle. I am not a star in codes so I don't know how to use your code exactly. The demo uses articles as divs arround the images. Can I use it this way?

 <div class="surrounding">
        <div class="single">
        
        <article class="entry video">
            <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="#">
            <img class="top1" src="images/knop-1.jpg" alt="">
            <span class="magnifier"></span>
            </a>
        </article>
 </div>

and so on.. I already see that this is not good. :(

Comment: Nevermind someone else helped me at work :)! it works now perfectly with 3 images next to each other. Some things in the JavaScript had to change and gave it a margin: 0 auto; to the article div. Anyway thanks for everything I am glad people here are so helpful!